# Selecting all fields (but one) instead of using asterix (*) decreases running time by 10 times

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sql wildcard: performance overhead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867946/sql-wildcard-performance-overhead)

Studying my applications preformance, I realized that the query:

```
SELECT * FROM (`static_cache`) WHERE `combined_name` =  'base'
```

Takes about 0.0052s to run. Sure, it might not be a lot, but a few of these querys quickly add up to a bit of loading time. Experimenting, I tried to select only the fields that I actually needed in the query instead (logical optimization), yielding the query:

```
SELECT `combined_name`, `timestamp`, `type`, `checksum` FROM (`static_cache`) 
       WHERE `combined_name` =  'base'
```

This query, however, takes as little as 0.0005s to run. That's **10 times faster**, and the only field and I am **not selecting is the id-column**. A speed increase was expected, but not by 10 times. Yes, I tested it repetitively.

**How can the change in this query possibly decrease the running time by so much?**

Comment: I actually tested to select ALL the fields, increasing the running time to 0.0012s, which still almost makes the query 5 times faster.

Comment: The overhead is from compiling the query, not from running it.  If you are using this query many times, then use a prepared statement.

Comment: @juergend I do not believe that my question is a duplicate, especially since my findings differ from the accepted answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is the planner really that slow in looking up the table column names? (even on a very quick query) :(

Comment: @Zar Consider updating the question to reflect your first comment/title.

Comment: @pst . . . presumably.  You can do the timings on your system.  The point is that the execution of the two queries is the same, unless the excluded column is really, really big.  A few milliseconds to compile and optimize a query is not particularly slow.  There's a reason why database vendors include prepared and pre-compiled queries.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can't argue with that .. although perhaps the above posted numbers are also off, if caching is getting the way?

Comment: @pst Caching is turned off in the PHP-environent, is there anywhere else I need to disable caching to get accurate results?